# Use a part of a link as a variable

Tags: jquery, html, variables

Having this link how can I get only the ?ref="THIS" part?? Because I want to pick only this part of the link with jQuery and then later use it as a variable.. Is this possible?? I want to do it when I'm loading the page. So:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    GET the variable (var variable = ref="THIS";)

    if(cookie != null){
    $("#"+variable).show().$.cookie("actual" , variable);

});
```

Html:

```
<a href="products.php?ref=oscilobatiente&tipo=7001ad></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6CUMW/3/)

Edit: I adjusted it so it works with objects now, thanks to some good comments by Thiefmaster

js

```
$(function() {
    var url = $("a").attr("href");
    var index = url.indexOf('?');
    var vars = url.substring(index + 1, url.length).split('&');
    var params = {} ;
    for(var i = 0; i < vars.length; i ++)
    {
        var param = vars[i].split('=');

        params[param[0]] = param[1];

    }
    alert(params.ref);
});​
```

Comment: `[]` the preferred way to create an array (instead of `new Array()`). However, you do not want an array in this case but an object (`var params = {};`) as you are using named fields. In case you wonder why your code works anyway: An `Array` is an object, too, so it can have properties. They won't be counted for its `.length` though.

Comment: @ThiefMaster well there you go then ^^

Comment: But when i use it it says undefined in the alert message

Answer (score 2):

ok so giving the A tag the id of myLink, you could do (note that the + 4 on the index is so that it doesn't include "ref=":

```
var myLinkHref = $("#myLink").attr("href");
var ref = myLinkHref.substring(myLinkHref.indexOf("ref=") + 4);
```